# Knowing the user name in a Page

Tags: asp.net, authentication

Let's assume the following:

- I have an IIS web site set up
- IIS is configured to use Digest authentication
- I'm running an ASP.NET page
- The page has a code-behing assembly that overrides Page_Load

When a user navigates to that page, I get a security prompt for the username and password.  If the username and password are *invalid* (i.e. incorrect password) is there a way for the called page, in Page_Load to know, or does IIS handle this and return the 401 before the ASP.NET engine ever gets around to resolving the actual Page class that will get executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using IIS authentication the webpage won't be compiled whatsoever if authentication fails.

If you can bypass this behavior I do not know, but its the default behavior. But since IIS use ntfs security I find it hard for the webserver to even be allowed to read the page in any case.

Comment: The code-behind is precompiled, but I don't think that matters.  I kind of suspected your answer, but am wondering if there's a way to subvert the behavior.

Comment: Ah yeah well.. as I don't really know and it's likely hard considering it's security on ntfs level. But I think it should be possible to have a custom 401 page if that is any help

Comment: A custom 401 might be a reasonable workaround for me if there's no way to get at it from the page (likely the case).